# What are the rules for pandas' elementwise binary boolean operands with same length elements holding differing indexes?

Tags: python, pandas

I have been applying some binary boolean operators about my code base and came across a bug that really surprised me. I've reconstructed a minimal working example to demonstrate the behavior below...

```
import pandas
s = pandas.Series( [True]*4 )
d = pandas.DataFrame( { 'a':[True, False, True, False] , 'b':[True]*4 } )

print(d)
       a     b
0   True  True
1  False  True
2   True  True
3  False  True

print( s[0:2] )
0    True
1    True
dtype: bool

print( d.loc[ d['a'] , 'b' ] )
0    True
2    True
dtype: bool

print( s[0:2] & d.loc[ d['a'] , 'b' ] )
0     True
1    False
2    False
```

This last statement's value catches me entirely by surprise in its yielding of 3 elements. Realizing the influence of indices here I manually reset the index to yield the result I expected.

```
s[0:2].reset_index(drop=True) & d.loc[ d['a'] , 'b' ].reset_index( drop=True )
0    True
1    True
```

Needless to say I'll need to revisit the documentation and get a grip to understand how the indexing rules apply here. Can any one explain step by step how this operator behaves with mixed indexes?

=============================================

Just to add comparison for those coming from a similar R background, R's `data.frame` equivalent operation yields what I'd expect...

```
> a = c(TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE)
> b = c(TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE)
> 
> d = data.frame( a, b )
> d
      a    b
1  TRUE TRUE
2 FALSE TRUE
3  TRUE TRUE
4 FALSE TRUE
> s = c( TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE)
> s
[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
>
> d[ d$a , 'b']
[1] TRUE TRUE
>
> s[0:2]
[1] TRUE TRUE
> s[0:2] & d[ d$a , 'b']
[1] TRUE TRUE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are comparing two series with different indices

```
s[0:2]

0    True
1    True
dtype: bool
```

and

```
d.loc[ d['a'] , 'b']

0    True
2    True
dtype: bool
```

---

`pandas` needs to align the indices then compares.

```
s[0:2] & d.loc[ d['a'] , 'b']

0     True  # True from both indices therefore True
1    False  # Only True from s[0:2] and missing from other therefore False
2    False  # Only True from d and missing from other therefore False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: wow, this index scheme is a whole new game coming from R's strictly elementwise operations. I'll integrate some R examples in my Question to offer some comparison. Thanks for the fundamental tip.

Comment: You can still do elementwise operations using the underlying numpy arrays (call `.values`  attribute on one of the Series/DataFrame).

Comment: wow, index alignment is a powerful feature... found a good demo and explanation of it here [What do I need to know about the pandas index? (Part 2)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=15q-is8P_H4). If I'm not mistaken there is no analogue to this in R, I think R's [recycling rules](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html#The-recycling-rule) would interject in the example the fella gives of a subset operation applied to a larger set where index alignment first occurs and NaN's are populated elsewhere.

Comment: @ayhan thanks for that good strategy. I won't play it in my case since I'm going to instead source all the independent `Series` and `DataFrame` constructors that share identical length to other `Series` and `DataFrames` they derive from. This time I will construct them to share the same index of their parent panda's object. These binary operations are found in many places, I need to align things from the get go with all these helper panda's objects. This discovery should fix several mysterious bugs I couldn't make sense of.